# Compiler couldn't read imported class

Tags: java, cmd, import, package

I have been trying to compile through CMD by creating packages manually. I tried the command `javac -d . Nameinfo.java` and `javac -d . Returndata.java`, where `Nameinfo` contains the calculations and `Returndata` contains main function, and this command worked absolutely fine. Now I made 2 different packages in my "java programmes" folder i.e `packx` and `packy`, where `packx` contains `Nameinfo` and `packy` contains `Returndata`. Now, when I compile these two, `Nameinfo.java` got compiled but `Returndata` could not read/recognize the imported `Nameinfo` in `Returndata.java`.

errors:

```
E:\java programmes>cd packx

E:\java programmes>cd packx

E:\java programmes\packx>javac Nameinfo.java

E:\java programmes\packx>cd..

E:\java programmes>cd packy

E:\java programmes\packy>javac Returndata.java
Returndata.java:2: error: package packx does not exist
import packx.Nameinfo;
            ^
Returndata.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
 Nameinfo data = new Nameinfo();
 ^
  symbol:   class Nameinfo
  location: class Returndata
Returndata.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
 Nameinfo data = new Nameinfo();
                     ^
  symbol:   class Nameinfo
  location: class Returndata
3 errors
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post and show `Nameinfo.java` and `Returndata.java`. I have a suspicion that the `package ...;` statements are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if java *or* javac needs, say, `packx.Returndata` as a type to do something, it will scour a classpath and/or sourcepath for a directory named `packx`, and within that, `Returndata.java` or `Returndata.class` depending on the tool and path we're talking about.

So, you're in `E:\java programmes\packy`, and you're compiling some code that imports packx. Therefore, javac will look in the classpath for `packx/Returndata.class` and in the sourcepath for `packx/Returndata.java` and it doesn't find what you want because `E:\java programmes` isn't on the source path; generally they default to `.` (i.e. the current directory).

Stay in the E:\java programmes folder for all this work:

```
E:
cd "\Java programmes"
javac packx/Nameinfo.java
javac packy/Returndata.java
```

Or better yet, realize that manually compiling a multipackage java application is crazy. Use `maven`, `gradle` or some other build tool that takes care of all this for you :)